# Changing backgound color of a subclassed button in Win32

Tags: c++, windows, button, colors, subclass

I want to change the background color of a button in runtime.

The problem is, the button does not have a black background which is what my code should produce.
Instead, it looks like is has the arrow of a drop-down control on it.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

First I subclassed the Button:

```
// HWND hParent is the parent window
// HINSTANCE hInstance is the current module
HWND h = CreateWindow("Button", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_OWNERDRAW, 
                      340, 10, 20, 20, 
                      hParent, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

SetWindowSubclass(h, &MyWndProc, MyButtonId, NULL);
```

The ID is defined as:

```
enum
{
    MyButtonId = 100,
};
```

And the subclass procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    if( uIdSubclass == MyButtonId )
    {
        switch( msg )
        {
        case WM_ERASEBKGND:
            {
                HDC dc = (HDC)wParam;
                SetBkColor(dc, RGB(127,127,127));
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not pass the button ID to the CreateWindow function, so your button does not have the ID you think it does.

The SetBkColor does not set backgrounds for buttons. It sets backgrounds for subsequent calls to TextOut.

You probably meant to use BS_OWNERDRAW, not SS_OWNERDRAW.

When you use the owner draw style you have to draw the button background and text and border. You do this in the parent window handler for WM_DRAWITEM. So you don't need to subclass the button at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I dont have the message loop of the parent window. So I need to subclass the button as far as I know.